# CentOS 8 - yum/dnf error: Failed to download metadata for repo

Tags: centos, repository, yum, dnf

On my CentOS 8 server, many `dnf` and `yum` commands fail with this error:

> Failed to download metadata for repo

This seems to apply only to repositories involving https connections, e.g.:

```
/etc/yum.repos.d $ cat epel-modular.repo
[epel-modular]
name=Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux Modular $releasever - $basearch/pub/epel/$releasever/Modular/$basearch
metalink=https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=epel-modular-$releasever&arch=$basearch&infra=$infra&content=$contentdir
...
```

I have used `wget` to test connectivity to these sites and it is successful, e.g. `wget https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org` succeeds.

However, various `dnf` or `yum` commands fail:

```
$ dnf provides /bin/ls
Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux Modular 8 - x86_64     0.0  B/s |   0  B     00:00
Failed to download metadata for repo 'epel-modular'
Error: Failed to download metadata for repo 'epel-modular'

# dnf update --refresh
CentOS-8 - AppStream                                        20 kB/s | 4.3 kB     00:00
CentOS-8 - Base                                             19 kB/s | 3.8 kB     00:00
CentOS-8 - Extras                                          7.4 kB/s | 1.5 kB     00:00
CentOS-8 - PowerTools                                       20 kB/s | 4.3 kB     00:00
Remi's Modular repository for Enterprise Linux 8 - x86_64  4.1 kB/s | 3.5 kB     00:00
Safe Remi's RPM repository for Enterprise Linux 8 - x86_64 3.6 kB/s | 3.0 kB     00:00
Wazuh repository                                           0.0  B/s |   0  B     00:00
Failed to download metadata for repo 'wazuh_repo'
Error: Failed to download metadata for repo 'wazuh_repo'
```

How do I resolve this problem?

Comment: You can have problems connecting to a repo for all kinds of reasons, so it is always good to use the dnf update -v (v for verbose) to get as much information as possible.

Comment: While I agree this is an off-topic question because it is the first hit in search engines, here is a possible solution: 
(I am aware I shouldn't answer this, but editing would be the bigger evil):

Check `/etc/yum/vars/releasever` if it contains a minor version edit: `sed -i 's/$releasever/8/g' /etc/yum.repos.d/epel*.repo` to reflect only the major version.
Taken from https://access.redhat.com/discussions/5473561

Answer (score 43):

In my case

```
sudo rm -r /var/cache/dnf
```

solved my problem.

Source: https://access.redhat.com/discussions/4222851

Comment: You could improve this answer by explaining why removing this folder resolves the issue.

Comment: Works for me after switching to CentOS 8 stream.

Answer (score 11):

I was getting the same error with the Centos8 build inside of a docker container. Fixed by running the below:

```
# Do on build
RUN dnf clean all && rm -r /var/cache/dnf  && dnf upgrade -y && dnf update -y
```

Error before (i was running yum update and not dnf):

```
Step 4/5 : RUN yum clean all && yum update -y && echo hostname -a
 ---> Running in 10d319da361d
0 files removed
CentOS-8 - AppStream                            0.0  B/s |   0  B     00:05    
Failed to download metadata for repo 'AppStream'
Error: Failed to download metadata for repo 'AppStream'
```

Success after:

```
 ---> 0b96049ee5eb
Step 4/5 : RUN dnf clean all && rm -r /var/cache/dnf  && dnf upgrade -y && dnf update -y & echo hostname
 ---> Running in f928c6da6cb0
hostname
Removing intermediate
```

Comment: dnf upgrade leads to the same error

Comment: running the whole string of commands or just that one? You may have a separate root cause than i had, sorry 

Answer (score 7):

I just faced this problem so I thought I'd add what fixed it for me since the resolution was pretty simple. For me, I was overlooking the fact that whenever I changed my hostname, it was wiping out everything in /etc/resolv.conf so I:

1. `nano -w /etc/resolv.conf` **
2. added the following lines:

   ```
   nameserver 8.8.8.8
   nameserver 8.8.4.4
   ```
3. Test it (e.g. `yum update -y`)

**note: I used nano in example, simply swap the `nano` portion for your own text editor of choice

Answer (score 3):

If it does not work, check your Internet connection. This error appeared on my CentOS 8 installation, and the problem was that the Internet connection wasn't correctly configured.

Comment: You were right, for people who has the same problem, add this line to your ```/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0``` file: ```ONBOOT=yes```. Original answer [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/79269/out-of-the-box-centos-in-virtualbox-nat-network-is-unreachable).

Answer (score 2):

Just add the following (DNS server) to  /etc/resolv.conf file:

```
nameserver 9.9.9.9
```

Will fix the issue :)

Comment: Can you explain why this fixes the issue? Is this a private DNS server, and if so, whose control is it under?

Comment: What is this supposed to do?

Comment: Dear @Yazan Yahya, you save my day. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You may not realize it, but **`yum` and `dnf` require SSL certificates when communicating via secure HTTP** (aka *HTTPS*).  Have you checked the certificates under `/etc/pki/tls/certs`?  There should be at least two, for example:

```
/etc/pki/tls/certs# ls -l
total 4
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   49 Jan 30 12:48 ca-bundle.crt -> /etc/pki/ca-trust/extracted/pem/tls-ca-bundle.pem
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   55 Dec 11 13:19 ca-bundle.trust.crt -> /etc/pki/ca-trust/extracted/openssl/ca-bundle.trust.crt
```

If these links are missing you may be able to simply restore them.  Otherwise, the files are part of the `ca-certificates` package.  You can obtain them from another server running your operating system via [yumdownloader](https://linux.die.net/man/1/yumdownloader) then restore your certificates from the resulting RPM file using `yum --nogpgcheck localinstall <RPM file>`.

Comment: you can download the package via `wget`, `curl`or any browser

Answer (score 0):

I was facing this issue when I tried to run

```
yum update -y
```

from a docker container. I changed the version from centos:8 to centos:7 and it solved the issue for me.

Comment: In `build/Dockerfile` is the "where" in my case

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error after I was messing around with SD adapter to microSD card. Edit `/etc/fstab` to remove SD line solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

I will confirm I recently had this issue and what fixed it for me was a change in the DNS servers. I had a static IP set but DNS was automatic, I had to reconfigure DNS to use my gateway and dc. This is working now.

Answer (score 0):

My issue was that the interface wasn't up after a fresh vm install.
Ran `ifconfig` to find my interface name and then `ifup eXXX` to get a dhcp ip address.

Also don't forget to change `ONBOOT=no` to `ONBOOT=yes` in `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eXXX` so it comes up during next boot.

Comment: In my case I had a static IP Address configured & was missing the DNS entry in that configuration. Following this guide to properly assigning a static IP on CentOS 8 fixed my issue: https://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-configure-a-static-ip-address-on-centos-8/