# Error using Yum DNF on Centos 8.1 Failed to download metadata for repo 'AppStream'

Tags: yum, centos8, dnf

Having great difficulty tracking down what is causing the below error when attempting to update any package from any repo. I have tested multiple repos by setting all others to disabled. I have cleaned all cache and removed any dnf yum cache files.

```
# dnf -v update
Loaded plugins: builddep, changelog, config-manager, copr, debug, debuginfo-install, download, generate_completion_cache, needs-restarting, playground, repoclosure, repodiff, repograph, repomanage, reposync
DNF version: 4.2.7
cachedir: /var/cache/dnf
repo: downloading from remote: AppStream
error: Curl error (28): Timeout was reached for http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=8&arch=x86_64&repo=AppStream&infra=stock [Resolving timed out after 30000 milliseconds] (http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=8&arch=x86_64&repo=AppStream&infra=stock).
CentOS-8 - AppStream                                                                                                                                                     0.0  B/s |   0  B     00:30    
Cannot download 'http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=8&arch=x86_64&repo=AppStream&infra=stock': Cannot prepare internal mirrorlist: Curl error (28): Timeout was reached for http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=8&arch=x86_64&repo=AppStream&infra=stock [Resolving timed out after 30000 milliseconds].
Failed to download metadata for repo 'AppStream'
Error: Failed to download metadata for repo 'AppStream'
```

Each time I attempt a dnf update, load average on the server goes thru the roof, up to 40x

curl can access the mirror site.

```
curl 'http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=8&arch=x86_64&repo=AppStream&infra=stock'
http://ftp.tc.edu.tw/Linux/CentOS/8.2.2004/AppStream/x86_64/os/
http://mirror.horizon.vn/centos/8.2.2004/AppStream/x86_64/os/
http://ftp.jaist.ac.jp/pub/Linux/CentOS/8.2.2004/AppStream/x86_64/os/
http://centosg9.centos.org/centos/8.2.2004/AppStream/x86_64/os/
http://packet01.centos.org/centos/8.2.2004/AppStream/x86_64/os/
http://mirror.s8.centos.org/centos/8.2.2004/AppStream/x86_64/os/
http://centoso7.centos.org/centos/8.2.2004/AppStream/x86_64/os/
http://centosh9.centos.org/centos/8.2.2004/AppStream/x86_64/os/
http://centosc8.centos.org/centos/8.2.2004/AppStream/x86_64/os/
http://centosg7.centos.org/centos/8.2.2004/AppStream/x86_64/os/
```

I have also tried using baserurl in .repo, same error

I have also replaced the baseurl with one of the url's returned by curl, same error

I have tried many suggestions such as [yum/dnf error: Failed to download metadata for repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59993633/yum-dnf-error-failed-to-download-metadata-for-repo)
and similar, none work for me.
Some articles point to bugs in the env vars for $releaseserver etc. I have also tried replacing with actual values. same error.

Internet connection obviously OK due to curl result.
No proxy used.
DNS OK

```
cat /etc/redhat-release
CentOS Linux release 8.1.1911 (Core)

uname -a
Linux xxxx 4.18.0-147.5.1.el8_1.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Feb 5 02:00:39 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I have the same problem. Literally banging my head now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some weird reasons, After setting the nameserver in `/etc/resolv.conf` to `8.8.8.8` and a reboot fixed the problem for me.

Also, I disabled the Dynamic memory for Hyper-V VM. DNF command is expecting a lot of memory.

Please give it a try.

Regards,
Arockiasamy

Comment: I added 8.8.8.8 to resolve.conf and commented out the original entries then rebooted the server. This worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: *** UPDATE *** This change only worked due to a reboot, then the problem came back after some time. It was happening across 4 servers, I then removed Cockpit and boom! Problem solved! So if you are experiencing this issue and have Cockpit install, try disabling or removing, it may help.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that worked for me was to disable and remove the offending repo.

```
sudo yum --disablerepo=epel\* remove epel-release.noarch
```

Answer (score 0):

Faced a similar issue while elevating cloudlinux 7.9 to 8 where yum and dnf gave error when update and issue was resolved when updated the repo for current OS. In my case:
**rpm -Uvh https://repo.cloudlinux.com/cloudlinux/8.7/BaseOS/x86_64/os/Packages/cloudlinux-release-8.7-2.el8.x86_64.rpm --force**

Hope this of some help.